# tables inside frameset 

Tags: html, jsp

Can I use tables inside a frameset in jsp?  I am new to jsp and don't know how it is possible? I am not using iFrames. Can any body please help me? i have two frames inside my frameset? I want those two frames inside a table. Is it possible? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the code that i am using

```
<frameset cols="100%,0" frameBorder="no" framespacing="0" border="0">

<frame  name="leftDualPane"  scrolling="no"
        src="<%=(String)session.getAttribute("tabViewJsp")%>"
      frameborder="1" style="border-left-width: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; 
border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
  </frame>

  <frame  name="rightDualPane"  scrolling="no"
      src="<%=(String)session.getAttribute("tabViewJsp")%>"
      frameborder="7" style="border-left-width: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; 
border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
  </frame>


</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSP is just the language you're using to generate HTML, and this is really an HTML question.  I think you need to trust your intuition about using IFRAMES rather than frames.